# Calculus and u-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to find: $$\int x^3\sqrt{1-x^2}\ dx$$

I’m not looking for the answer I am only seeking a better understanding of how $u$-substitution would be used to solve this problem.

According to the answer provided you are supposed to define $u$ as $u=1-x^2$.

This is where I am getting confused as $du=-2x$ but this is no where in the function, and this is what was given as the next step in the problem:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int u^{3/2}-\sqrt{u} \ du$$

So my question is where exactly did $\frac{1}{2}\int u^{3/2}$ as well as the subtraction come from? Thank you in advance for any explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we substitute $u = 1- x^2 \implies du = -2x \, dx$, we get, $$I = \int x^3\sqrt{1-x^2} \, dx = \int \frac{1}{2} (-x^2)(-2x)\sqrt{1-x^2} \, dx$$ $$=\int \frac{1}{2}((1-x^2)-1)\sqrt{1-x^2}(-2x) \, dx$$ $$=\int \frac{1}{2}(u-1) \sqrt{u} \, du$$ $$= \frac12[\int u^{\frac32}\, du - \int \sqrt{u}\, du]$$

Answer (score 0):

If $u=1-x^2$ then $du=-2xdx,$ which gives
$$\int x^3\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\int x(1-u)\sqrt{u}\frac{du}{x}=-\frac{1}{2}\int\left(\sqrt{u}-u^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)du=...$$

Comment: The hint here to use $u=1-x^2$ is better for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{du}{dx}=-2x$$
as you say, and
$$x^3\sqrt{1-x^2}=-\frac{x^2}2\sqrt{1-x^2}\frac{du}{dx}
=-\frac{1-u}2\sqrt u\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u^{3/2}-u^{1/2}}{2}\frac{du}{dx}.$$
This means that
$$\int x^3\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx=\int \frac{u^{3/2}-u^{1/2}}{2}\,du.$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:
$$\int x^3\sqrt{1-x^2} \, dx=\frac12\int x^2\sqrt{1-x^2} \, dx^2 \stackrel{x^2=t}=\frac12\int t\sqrt{1-t} \, dt\stackrel{\text{by parts}}=$$
$$\frac12\cdot t\cdot \left(-\frac23(1-t)^{3/2}\right)-\frac12 \int \left(-\frac23(1-t)^{3/2}\right)dt=$$
$$\frac13t(1-t)^{3/2}-\frac{2}{15}(1-t)^{5/2}+C=$$
$$\frac13x^2(1-x^2)^{3/2}-\frac{2}{15}(1-x^2)^{5/2}+C.$$